# How to insert an ellipse (circle) in docX?

Tags: docx4j

I'm trying to insert an ellipse in a docx without sucess. It is possible to add an ellipse to docx with docx4j? I also tried to insert the XML "....." with org.docx4j.XmlUtils.unmarshalString but I received some errors.

Someone tried to do it?

Comment: What did your unmarshalString code look like, and what error did you get?

Comment: Jason thank you for the answer. I was forgeting to insert the namespaces in the w:p. Now it was working very well.